# AppBarLayout: how to removeOnOffsetChangedListener

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, android-appbarlayout

In order to detect finish of app bar collapsing I called `addOnOffsetChangedListener`. In listener's `onOffsetChanged` I catch and handle the moment of collapsing done. Then I need to stop listen for offset changes.

In most examples here is call of `removeOnOffsetChangedListener(this)` from inside of `onOffsetChanged`. But looking in AppBarLayout.java I see:

```
private void dispatchOffsetUpdates(int offset) {
    // Iterate backwards through the list so that most recently added listeners
    // get the first chance to decide
    if (mListeners != null) {
        for (int i = 0, z = mListeners.size(); i < z; i++) {
            final OnOffsetChangedListener listener = mListeners.get(i);
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onOffsetChanged(this, offset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if there is more than one listener installed, calling `removeOnOffsetChangedListener(this)` naturally results in `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Have I missed something? Is there **safe** way to 'unsubscribe' from listening for offset updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, this wouldn't be a problem if their code actually did what the comment says. Anyway, we can defer the removal by putting the call to `removeOnOffsetChangedListener()` in a `Runnable`, and posting it to the `AppBarLayout` in `onOffsetChanged()`, instead of calling it directly there.

For example:

```
AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener listener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(final AppBarLayout abl, int offset) {
        abl.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    abl.removeOnOffsetChangedListener(listener);
                }
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: It's the solution, thank you!
But why "this wouldn't be a problem if their code actually did what the comment says"? Having, for example, two items in list before entering the cycle, that code definitely causes IOOB while calling `mListeners.get(1)` on the second pass after removing the first item.
There better do the job with iterator.

Comment: If they went backwards - i.e., started at `i = mListeners.size() - 1`, and decremented `i` instead - removing an element would still shrink the `List`, but it wouldn't hit an index that doesn't exist, since it's going to `0`. It seems like they meant to change it, but goofed; a bad merge, or something. The comment sounds incomplete.